# How about putting some effort on old low-quality questions?

Tags: support

I just checked some old questions today by going to the active tab and then moved to [50k+ pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=50000&sort=active).

I found many low-quality posts that should be removed which are **Low quality**/ **primarily opinion based** and so on.

I flagged it, but I wonder the questions are stayed there for months.

**The main reason they didn't get removed is because they are tagged under less active tags.**

Here are two examples:

1. [creating libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745531/creating-libraries)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748691/piranha-cms-database

So, I think we should take more effort to flag / delete such questions to improve the site quality.

Comment: Adding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748644/liking-photos-in-instagram-by-php

Comment: Oh wow, [your edit to that second question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37748691/revisions) is such a *stellar* example of putting effort into editing a low quality question...

Comment: I flagged it first and then corrected the grammar @BoltClock

Comment: Sometimes, it's better to just downvote these... less time spent by the community as whole.

Comment: @SagarV Why make such a trivial change to a post that doesn't actually meaningfully improve it while also flagging it for deletion?

Comment: @Braiam per day 40 vote limit

Comment: @Servy Flagged it and I am sure it will be deleted. But I saw a grammar mistake so I just corrected it.

Comment: @SagarV Looks like you very rarely even come close to actually using all of your votes in a day, so start there.

Comment: @Servy for last few days, I am using all my votes and for last few weeks, I am using all my flags. Today only 7 votes left

Comment: @SagarV And yet you left *lots* of other formatting problems with the post, you made a change that doesn't actually improve basically anything at all (that sentence fragment still isn't anywhere close to being correct) and if it actually gets deleted any edits along those lines will be rendered pointless anyway.  Spend time editing posts that *can actually be salvaged* and when you do, actually take the time to meaningfully improve it with your edit.

Comment: @Servy copied clear.

Comment: Adding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108563/will-instagram-block-getting-hashtag-public-content-after-june-1

Comment: Also, you changed the comma to a period but there are no spaces before punctuation in English.

Comment: The intention is noble, but old low quality questions like that are a millions-strong cesspool. There's probably more productive ways to expend energy on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree, Even my this post too may have lots of mistakes. I am not so good at english I accept. But I told already. Just made a swap of `it` and `is`

Comment: one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749520/using-strptime-to-extract-only-time-from-a-column-in-r

Comment: @SagarV viewed 49 times..... no answer, 1 vote (down).... why should it be improved? what is the site benefiting from by improving it?

Comment: I already answered to this in the 3rd and 4th comment in the answer. It is my mistake

Comment: @SagarV you did! I read the answer after going through these comments :p. Apologies!

Comment: No need. It is my mistake. I didn't make the question clear.

Answer (score 10):

Old low quality questions that barely got attention - those aren't a problem.

What is a problem, is the amount of low quality questions coming in now. These are the ones that appear on the front page, and need to be improved or deleted.

Editing old low-quality questions bumps them to the front page - adding to the noise.
Only edit these if you can actually salvage them. But if that's what you want - it's probably better to go to the Help & Improvement queue, and see if you can salvage questions that people have now. Rather than questions that (in all likelihood) have long been abandoned by the original askers.

Or, you could try and earn 3000 points. Then you get the Close-Vote privilege, and help with the Close Votes review queue.

Comment: As the mentioned sample posts ( link in question and comment) I am not talking about the can-be-improved question. I am talking about the can-be-deleted questions which very easy rather than editing.

Comment: @SagarV But you stated in your question that we should *" take more effort to edit / flag such questions"* (which you also did yourself). This is what this answer is talking about. If you really just mean we should get those questions deleted and *not* edited you might want to edit that out of this question to clear up some potential confusion.

Comment: Ok I accept. But my mistake on converting content from Mind to MSO.

Comment: I actually meant that give more priority to Deletion

Comment: @SagarV Then go and get those 3000 points. Then you can be effective in the Close Votes queue. (But, make sure you have a good understanding of what should be closed and what should not!)

Comment: Also, If there are spam links, **it will come in front page because the Community user already started the process of converting http to https** for all posts that have links. So it will be modified and will come on first page

Comment: @S.L.Barth not that easy. Heavy competetion in [javascript] and very difficult to get Rep from there :-)

Comment: So pick a tag related to javascript that you're familiar with and focus on those. Note however that the lesser tags will have less traffic, and therefore less potential for rep gains.

Comment: I have somewhat knowledge on JS, regex, jQuery, CSS and HTML and a little on PHP. All of them are high traffic tags. I am trying hard to gain 3k+ because , I am already spending 7-9 hours per day in SO. so , I think I can contribute more by using the cast close vote privilege. But since the tags are heavy traffic, it may take time. So I need your support to close questions. I already gave some question links here. So consider closing it. Till I gain 3k+, I will try to add the question link either here as a comment or SOCVR Chat room @KevinB

Comment: Up/Downvotes are far more effective than casting close votes (unless you're dupehammering)

Comment: I cast many of my votes in new question and answers in the morning itself. 40 vote is not enought in such cases

Comment: Sure you can, 40 times a day. Once you run out, come back tmorrow. Casting close votes doesn't have immedaite feedback and often just results in wasted effort when your close votes timeout and fade away.